# Duplicate keys in map

Tags: java

I have a list of papers and each paper has a set of keyword assigned to it. I want to get a Map, which will store the keyword and total sum of its frequencies in all papers. I have implemented as following:

```
public Map<Keyword, Integer> getKeywordFrequencies(List<Integer> userPapers,
            Map<Integer, List<PaperKeywordMapping>> paperKeywords) {
        Map<Keyword, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
        for (Integer ind : userPapers) {
            for (PaperKeywordMapping pKeyword : paperKeywords.get(ind)) {
                frequencies.compute(pKeyword.getKeyword(), (k, v) -> {
                    return v == null ? pKeyword.getTermFrequency() : v + pKeyword.getTermFrequency();
                });
            }
        }
        frequencies.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("keyword : " + k.getKeywordName() + " freq : " + v));
        return frequencies;
    }
```

The issue is that, I am getting not unique keys in the map. Here is output:

```
keyword : Nonfiction freq : 60
keyword : Reference freq : 38
keyword : Sports freq : 263
keyword : Arts freq : 90
keyword : Astronomy freq : 50
keyword : Medicine freq : 16
keyword : Applied freq : 31
keyword : History freq : 106
keyword : Discrete freq : 47
keyword : microeconomics freq : 68
keyword : macroeconomics freq : 41
keyword : Nonfiction freq : 99
keyword : Reference freq : 101
keyword : Sports freq : 262
keyword : Arts freq : 126
keyword : Astronomy freq : 58
keyword : Medicine freq : 31
```

Tried to add check, if the key exists or no, but still the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a Set to guarantee unique keys

Comment: Your keyword object needs to implement a proper `equals` method.

Comment: @Marvin, the implementation is there already.

Comment: What @Marvin said, or just use `String`s as the keys instead.

Comment: @huck_cussler does it really needs to be done using strings (i.e. keyword names)? I used ids, whis are also unique

Comment: You're showing hashcode and equals for `KeywordTaxonomy`, but your map is using `Keyword`.

Comment: @Cap No it doesn't have to be done with `String`s, that was just a suggestion.

Comment: @azurefrog, my failure! Edited already, but no changes in output

Comment: If everything is ok with hashCode and equals, then the problem is with putting key/values into this map. Try to replace compute with simple put. Compute is not for this in Java.

Comment: How is keywordName generated, you could have unique IDs who have the same keywordName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is unique key for HashMap?
It's identified by hashCode and equals methods.
To have this property working correctly you need to define these methods in your Keyword class.